# Perl Encode.pm cannot decode string with wide character

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

I was running a perl app which uses `/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Encode.pm`

and issues an error

> Cannot decode string with wide characters at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Encode.pm line 174.

Line 174 of `Encode.pm` reads

```
sub decode($$;$) {
    my ( $name, $octets, $check ) = @_;
    return undef unless defined $octets;
    $octets .= '' if ref $octets;
    $check ||= 0;
    my $enc = find_encoding($name);
    unless ( defined $enc ) {
        require Carp;
        Carp::croak("Unknown encoding '$name'");
    }
    my $string = $enc->decode( $octets, $check );  # line 174
    $_[1] = $octets if $check and !ref $check and !( $check & LEAVE_SRC() );
    return $string;
}
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
`$enc->decode( $octets, $check );`  expects octets.

So put `Encode::_utf8_off($octets)` before. It made it work for me.

Comment: Never use `_utf8_off`. Using this function is inherently buggy because `_utf8_off($s)` is short for `utf8::encode($s) if is_utf8($s);`. Either encode or don't, but don't do it based on something random!

Answer (score 14):

`encode` takes a string of Unicode code points and serialises them into a string of bytes.

`decode` takes a string of bytes and deserialises them into Unicode code points.

That message means you passed a string containing one or more characters above 255 (non-bytes) to `decode`, which is obviously an incorrect argument.

```
>perl -MEncode -E"for (254..257) { say; decode('iso-8859-1', chr($_)); }"
254
255
256
Wide character in subroutine entry at .../Encode.pm line 176.
```

You ask for a workaround, but the bug is yours. Perhaps you are accidentally trying to decode something you already decoded?

Comment: User input is rarely well formatted and I have to deal with badly-encoded files all the time. It would be nice if `decode` could skip over the invalid chars, but on my machine, even with `Encode::FB_QUIET` passed as a third argument, it still dies.

Comment: @rjh, That has nothing to do with the OP's problem. His problem has nothing to do with badly encoded files.

Comment: that is untrue. I found this answer because I'm getting the same error trying to decode a badly encoded input file. Specifically GB18030 encoded using an ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion but also containing valid UTF-8 sequences (!).

Comment: @rjh, "Wide character" errors cannot come from a badly encoded file. It's impossible for a file to contain these wide characters. Either the error you are getting is different and your question is different than the OP's, or you are mistaken about the cause of your error. I'll be happy to look into it if you post a proper question with a proper demonstration of your problem.

Comment: thanks, you were correct, I was able to fix it with the appropriate decode() and encode() calls.

Answer (score 2):

That error message is saying that you have passed in a string that has already been decoded (and contains characters above codepoint 255).  You can't decode it again.