# perl Encode::_utf8_off in python

Tags: python, perl

What is Python's equivalent function of Perl's `Encode::_utf8_off` ?

Comment: Don't give the name of a function in another language, say what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** ever use `Encode::_utf8_off`.

You are probably trying to encode a string using UTF-8. In Perl, you'd could use any of the following:

- `utf8::encode($s);`
- `utf8::encode( my $utf8 = $uni );`
- `use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );  my $utf8 = encode_utf8($uni);`
- `use Encode qw( encode );  my $utf8 = encode('UTF-8', $uni);`

I don't know Python, but a quick search finds

```
utf8 = uni.encode('UTF-8', 'strict')
```

Comment: My problem is something similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994100/perl-encode-pm-cannot-decode-string-with-wide-character 

Encode::_utf8_off solved my problem. But a part of my script is in python and the python script is having the same issue. So I was looking for the same function in python so that I can apply there.

Comment: I repeat: NEVER USE `Encode::_utf8_off`. Meng Lu was passing something that wasn't encoded to `decode`. The solution to Meng Lu's problem wasn't to add `_utf8_off`. The solution was to fix their buggy code.

Comment: Hey.. thanks i will try utf::downgrade. But just wondering, can you please explain why I should NEVER use Encode::_utf8_off ?

Comment: Because sometimes it does `utf8::encode`, and sometimes it does nothing at all.